# GLSL program wrong execution

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl

I am experiencing some very strange visual bugs when running our GLSL(300 es) shader programs on Samsung Galaxy Note 4 device. It has a Quallcom Adreno(TM)420 gpu, which supports GLES2.0 and GLES3.0. We have quite complex shader programs which we use to render effects like BRDF, shadow mapping etc.

The above mentioned device doesn't present the shadows at all (till we found the place in the code that caused it, see further). Also lights shading behavior is wrong.
The same programs work fine on the following hardware:
PC (PowerVR GLES emulator),iOS(6-7),Samsung Galaxy A7,Samsung Galaxy S6,Meizu M5,Xiaomi 4A,Motorola Nexus 6

In case of the shadows we had this chunk of code:

```
bool InRange(float val)
{
   return val >= 0.0 && val <= 1.0;
}

float shadowFunc (sampler2D shadowMap, vec4 lightClipPosition, float bias)

{
  vec3 shadowMapCoords = lightClipPosition.xyz / lightClipPosition.w;
  shadowMapCoords = (shadowMapCoords + 1.0) / 2.0;
  //...some more code
  if (!InRange (shadowMapCoords.z)
    || !InRange (shadowMapCoords.x)
    || !InRange (shadowMapCoords.y))
    return 1.0;
  //...some more code
}
```

Where the if() statement with 3 calls to

> InRange()

method was causing the shadows not to show up at all.Changing to

```
if ((shadowMapCoords.x < 0.0 || shadowMapCoords.x > 1.0 || shadowMapCoords.y < 0.0 || shadowMapCoords.y > 1.0 || shadowMapCoords.z < 0.0 || shadowMapCoords.z > 1.0)) 
 {
     return 1.0;       
 }
```

Fixed it.

Important to note, there are no errors during shader compilations or during run-time.

Now I wonder, is this a kind of rule dictated by the GLSL compiler or by the driver? Are there any limitation to the amount of function executions in a shader body? I am completely aware that my shader uses quite a lot of function calls. (Didn't get to the optimization phase yet). But all those shaders run fine on all the other phones I tested. That's why I am not sure the real problem is in my code.

Do I have to inline all the methods found in the shader into shader's 'main' function to get all our stuff to work correctly on this device?

Or maybe it's just the driver bug?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this looks like a straight driver bug; it should work fine.

That said, please don't write code like this ... it makes shader cores cry with the volume of branches.

Ideally just clamp your values to be between 0 and 1 and run the shader; it will probably look OK if you design your algorithm boundary conditions correctly, and often just running the shadowing code will be cheaper than the early-out.

If you really must use conditional code, try to use the vector built-in functions, they are often backed by hardware assist:

```
if (any(greaterThan(shadowMapCoords, 1.0)) || any(lessThan(shadowMapCoords, 0.0))) { ... }
```